# What to use In place of getDrawable(int) in lower API like 15

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I am writing an app where I use below code but it's for **API 21** and above.

```
ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tickcross);
i.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.weirdtick));
```

What can I use for lower API like **15**?

Comment: I changed  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1' to  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2' syncing it did not work please help

Comment: I have compile 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:25.0.1' changing it to 2 it dnt sys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html):

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.weirdtick)
```

Please be noted that you also need to add v4 support library to use the **ContextCompat**. You can add it by adding the following line in your project build.gradle dependencies:

```
// Change version 25.0.2  to your installed version.
compile com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.2
```

Read more for Support Library: [Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html)
.

Comment: Tried to install the repository but was unable to download it. what can I do?

Comment: I have   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1' on my pc when I changed it to   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'

Comment: Any error? Have you add `import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;` ?

Comment: Maybe I missing something here. Is "all is now working" or "all is not working"?

Comment: After adding ContextCompat whenever I run the app it stops unfortunately. Please offer a solution

Comment: what error? Please post the logcat or the error log.

Comment: Try using only the support-v4 as in my answer. Afaik, you need to change your activity to AppCompatActivity and change the theme to appCompat them if you use appcompat-v7

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.image1)`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.drawable1);`
is `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.blue,customTheme);`.
The difference is latter one takes one more parameter as `Resources.Theme theme` or just give null.
If you have a custom theme you can use the latter one.